Creating Data for SEM model in Amos
I need to generate data for SEM model in Amos. I've tried excel, python, is there anyone to recommend how to get significant positive effect between variables if I show the model, maybe model has some issue or something else is needed. I've tried everything I could, theoretical background for model is legit and checked a lot of times.
I had actual data and i got negative impact while its not logically possible, then tried to generate data in excel with more than 0.5 correlation between columns, didn't work, in the end wrote a code to generate data according to model and to get positive significant effect between variables in Python and got error at all.
